# How do I bind a terminal command to the execution of a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Say I have a programme that's run from a shell script:

```
cd /path/to/file/
./programme
```

How would I bind that to a single command so I only have to type one thing? ie for most installed programmes I can just type the name of the programme and it's running

```
programme
```

Comment: add `/path/to/file` to your `$PATH`

Comment: create a function or an alias

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add your script path in `$PATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` file ,like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/file
```

or put your script in linux binary directory like `/usr/local/bin` , `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create a script with a name and give execute permission to it. Then Copy that script to /usr/bin directory .  Now you can run your scrpt as a command in terminal. For details please refer the link https://devopsmanual.in/2018/04/17/create-our-own-script-in-linux/

Comment: Please don't put your own scripts in `/usr/bin`, that is for system-wide commands and stuff in there may get replaced during system updates. Create your per-user scripts directory, e.g., `~/scripts`, and add that to the user's `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` or al.